# Parsing Json to Java Object

Tags: java, json

got this problem:
Json:

```
{"authenticationToken":{"token":"c9XXXX1-XXXX-4XX9-XXXX-41XXXXX3XXXX"}}
```

Object:

```
    public class AuthenticationToken {
 public AuthenticationToken() {

 }

 public AuthenticationToken(String token) {
  authenticationToken = token;
 }

    @JsonProperty(value="token")
    private String authenticationToken;


 public String getAuthenticationToken() {
  return authenticationToken;
 }

 public void setAuthenticationToken(String authenticationToken) {
  this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
 }
}
```

But i got a a error in logs: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "authenticationToken" (class de.regalfrei.android.AuthenticationToken), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "token"]) and i do not have any idea how to set the JSON properties correct for this situation. Can someone help?

As you said i added a Wrapperclass:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenWrapper {
    AuthenticationToken authenticationToken;

    public AuthenticationTokenWrapper(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
        this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value="authenticationToken")
    public AuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken() {
        return authenticationToken;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
        this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
    }

}
```

and called this function:

```
AuthenticationTokenWrapper tok =restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, AuthenticationTokenWrapper.class);
```

Comment: You probably have to write a custom deserializer here...

Comment: Hi, what dies this mean? custom deserializer?

Comment: That or use the `@JsonUnwrap` annotation.

Comment: which deserializer are you using?

Comment: I tried this:  @JsonUnwrapped
    public AuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken() { but also got this error Could not read JSON: No _valueDeserializer assigned
        at

Comment: what do you mean with which deserializer?

Comment: I don't have experience with Spring. I am using jackson deserializer for JSON deserialization. Which can be done as follows.

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
AuthenticationTokenWrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(jsonString, AuthenticationTokenWrapper.class);

where jsonString is the string containing JSON value.

Comment: Ok, this maybe works. but is not exactly this whole thing for load a json output of a rest service into own java objects like authenticationToken ?

Comment: Do you actually want your token to serialize to `{ "authenticationToken": { "token": "whatever" } }` or just `{ "token": "whatever" }`?

Comment: the webserice is already done and is in used for different other apps. and there it is like this: { "authenticationToken": { "token": "whatever" } } and so i have to handle this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a wrapper class which have a variable named `authenticationToken` which is an object of `AuthenticationToken`

in order to parse your JSON correctly, create a wrapper class like this

```
public class Wrapper {
private AuthenticationToken authenticationToken;

public Wrapper(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
    this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
}

public AuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken() {
    return authenticationToken;
}

public void setAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
    this.authenticationToken = authenticationToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. i got this: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class de.myapp.android.AuthenticationTokenWrapper]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: Is the @JsonProperty(value="authenticationToken") in the wrapper class correct? i also tried instead this: @JsonUnwrapped but also does not work..

Comment: I am using Jackson deserializer which does not require explicit annotation when the getter and setter methods are with the same name as the variables. Other deserializers may need explicit annotations.

Comment: where can i see which deserializer i use? i think am using also jackson?!

Comment: I don't know which deserializer would Spring use, I think [this](http://blog.jdriven.com/2012/11/consume-rest-json-webservices-easily-using-spring-web/) will help.

Comment: I have solved it..

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    
            System.out.println(restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, String.class));
            AuthenticationTokenWrapper tok =restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, AuthenticationTokenWrapper.class)   ;

i used `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instead of `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. but now it worked with the wrapper class as you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this...

Maybe the error is here     private String authenticationToken;
You are saying authenticationToken is a string, but according to the JSON Object it is another JSON Object. Try converting it into JSON Object and access the token.

Comment: Hi, you mean the same thing like Manu Viswam correct? this i tried and does not work :(

Comment: @ludwigmi I don't understand what he says... I am saying that you can access it as JSONObject a=new JSONObject('{"authenticationToken":{"token":"c9XXXX1-XXXX-4XX9-XXXX-41XXXXX3XXXX"}}'); you can access token as               Sysout(((JSONObject)a.get("authenticationToken")).get("token").toString());  Note: I am using org.json.jar It works for me.

Comment: Hi, yes, this i think will work. But i want to load this JASON into my Java Object Class AuthenticationToken.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@JsonProperty(value="authenticationToken")
private String authenticationToken;
```

then un-marshall that string into another class with

```
@JsonProperty(value="token")
private String tokenStr;
```